# Need help to put values from one peer XML group to another XML group

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below input XML structure and target output. Each Payroll_Result_Lines_group will have one output record "Worker".
Question I have is on Column5 that is supposed to be the YTD Wage under "Payroll_Result_group". It should be based on the wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group/ wd:Deduction/@ Deduction_Code value.

Below is the XSL I have so far. I realized the variables deduction_code and ytd_wage are only evaluated once per each worker as I place them on the Report_Entry level. That resulted in 
If I place these variables inside wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group, then ytd_wage returns nothing as group "Payroll_Result_group" is not under "Payroll_Result_Lines_group". Any advice?

Input XML:

```
<wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Account_ID>123456</wd:Account_ID>
    <wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group>
        <wd:Tax_Description>W_FWFEDERAL</wd:Tax_Description>
        <wd:Deduction wd:Descriptor="Federal Withholding [USA]">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Deduction_Code">W_FW</wd:ID>
        </wd:Deduction>
        <wd:YTD_Withheld>1111</wd:YTD_Withheld>
    </wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group>
    <wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group>
        <wd:Tax_Description>W_MEDFEDERAL</wd:Tax_Description>
        <wd:Deduction wd:Descriptor="Medicare [USA]">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Deduction_Code">W_MED</wd:ID>
        </wd:Deduction>
        <wd:YTD_Withheld>1112</wd:YTD_Withheld>
    </wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group>
    <wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group>
        <wd:Tax_Description>W_OASFEDERAL</wd:Tax_Description>
        <wd:Deduction wd:Descriptor="OASDI [USA]">
            <wd:ID wd:type="Deduction_Code">W_OAS</wd:ID>
        </wd:Deduction>
        <wd:YTD_Withheld>1113</wd:YTD_Withheld>
    </wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group>
    <wd:Payroll_Result_group>
        <wd:YTD_Supplemental_Wage>66</wd:YTD_Supplemental_Wage>
        <wd:YTD_Federal_Wage>1000</wd:YTD_Federal_Wage>
        <wd:YTD_Medicare_Wage>2000</wd:YTD_Medicare_Wage>
        <wd:YTD_OASDI_Wage>3000</wd:YTD_OASDI_Wage>
        <wd:YTD_State_Wage>4000</wd:YTD_State_Wage>
    </wd:Payroll_Result_group>
</wd:Report_Entry>
```

Output:

```
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <Column1 maxlen="11">808452</Column1>
        <Column2 maxlen="15">W_FWFEDERAL</Column2>
        <Column3 maxlen="13">1111</Column3>
        <Column4 maxlen="13">66</Column4>
        <Column5 maxlen="13"/>1000</ Column5>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Column1 maxlen="11">808452</Column1>
        <Column2 maxlen="15">W_MEDFEDERAL</Column2>
        <Column3 maxlen="13">1112</Column3>
        <Column4 maxlen="13">66</Column4>
        <Column5 maxlen="13"/>2000</ Column5>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Column1 maxlen="11">808452</Column1>
        <Column2 maxlen="15">W_OASFEDERAL</Column2>
        <Column3 maxlen="13">1113</Column3>
        <Column4 maxlen="13">66</Column4>
        <Column5 maxlen="13"/>3000</ Column5>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
            <xsl:variable name="account_id" select="wd:Account_ID"/>
            <xsl:variable name="ytd_supp_wage" select="wd:Payroll_Result_group/wd:YTD_Supplemental_Wage"/>
            <xsl:variable name="deduction_code" select="wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group/wd:Deduction/wd:ID[2]"/> 
            <xsl:variable name="ytd_wage">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$deduction_code='W_FW'"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Payroll_Result_group/wd:YTD_Federal_Wage"/></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$deduction_code = 'W_MED'"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Payroll_Result_group/wd:YTD_Medicare_Wage"/></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$deduction_code = 'W_OAS'"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Payroll_Result_group/wd:YTD_OASDI_Wage"/></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$deduction_code = 'W_SWW'"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Payroll_Result_group/wd:YTD_State_Wage"/></xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>                   
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group">
                <Worker >
                    <Column1 xtt:maxLength="11"><xsl:value-of select="$account_id"/></Column1>
                    <Column2 xtt:maxLength="15"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Tax_Description"/></Column2>   
                    <Column3 xtt:maxLength="13"><xsl:value-of select="wd:YTD_Withheld"/></Column3>
                    <Column4 xtt:maxLength="13"><xsl:value-of select="$ytd_supp_wage"/></Column4>
                    <Column5 xtt:maxLength="13"><xsl:value-of select="$ytd_wage"/></Column5>                        
                </Worker>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Workers>      
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What XSLT version can you use?

Comment: should be version 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the declaration of the `deduction_code` and `ytd_wage` variables inside the `xsl:for-each` of `wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group`, as they really depend on the worker you are processing.

Trying this XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">
    <Workers>
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
            <xsl:variable name="account_id" select="wd:Account_ID"/>
            <xsl:variable name="ytd_supp_wage" select="wd:Payroll_Result_group/wd:YTD_Supplemental_Wage"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="wd:Payroll_Result_Lines_group">
                <xsl:variable name="deduction_code" select="wd:Deduction/wd:ID"/> 
                <xsl:variable name="ytd_wage">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$deduction_code = 'W_FW'"><xsl:value-of select="../wd:Payroll_Result_group/wd:YTD_Federal_Wage"/></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$deduction_code = 'W_MED'"><xsl:value-of select="../wd:Payroll_Result_group/wd:YTD_Medicare_Wage"/></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$deduction_code = 'W_OAS'"><xsl:value-of select="../wd:Payroll_Result_group/wd:YTD_OASDI_Wage"/></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$deduction_code = 'W_SWW'"><xsl:value-of select="../wd:Payroll_Result_group/wd:YTD_State_Wage"/></xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>                   
                </xsl:variable>
                <Worker>
                    <Column1 xtt:maxLength="11"><xsl:value-of select="$account_id"/></Column1>
                    <Column2 xtt:maxLength="15"><xsl:value-of select="wd:Tax_Description"/></Column2>   
                    <Column3 xtt:maxLength="13"><xsl:value-of select="wd:YTD_Withheld"/></Column3>
                    <Column4 xtt:maxLength="13"><xsl:value-of select="$ytd_supp_wage"/></Column4>
                    <Column5 xtt:maxLength="13"><xsl:value-of select="$ytd_wage"/></Column5>                        
                </Worker>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Workers>      
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Somehow I thought I can't access parent level within Payroll_Result_Lines_group. That works!